# add a supplier attribute from res.partner to another table in odoo13

Tags: python, model, odoo-13

I am using odoo13 I am developping my own application and I need to add supplier attribute from res.partner to a class . the relation is many2one and I want just the list of suppliers not all the entries of res.partner
this is what I tried in class declaration :
"partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Supplier', supplier_rank='1', required=True)"

Answer (score 0):

in xml: `<field name="partner_id" string="Fournisseur" domain="[('supplier_rank','=','1')]"`
on_change="on_change_partner(partner_id)"/>
class py : `"partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Supplier')"`